# Clear all text in separate file

Tags: python

I want to know how to delete/clear all text inside another Python file.

Comment: What do you mean "in a file inside another python file"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as you would a text file:

```
with open("file_to_clear.py", "w") as file:
    file.write("")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
open('yourfile.txt', 'w').close()
```